Lost 2 of 24 words (12th&24th) on TON SPACE
I have made bad screenshot of mnemonic phrase, and lost access from Ton Space, 12th and 24th words are missing, i know all other words in a proper order, so only 2 are missing. Do you guys know any options to recover it with Python or any other codes, as I understand it gets harder as its TON Space and not trust wallet for example.
Also I know wallet from Ton Space, maybe its possible to put it to the code so it will make no mistakes.
Appreciate all of your help

Welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange .com, your question doesn't seem to be about Bitcoin but about the TON crypto currency.

This is not relevant for this forum.
